# can you image this code can run without error?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

i think it must be out of index,but it  runs well ,confused so much

```py
tuple1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
count = len(tuple1);
print(count)
print(tuple1[count + 1])
```

Comment: Would you please add `print(type(tuple1))`, and `print(len)`, and show _all_ the output?

Comment: [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) doesn't return a list, but an iterable. Therefore, the subscriptions don't necessarily throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

[pygame.key.get_pressed()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) doesn't return a list, but an iterable. Therefore, the subscriptions don't necessarily throw an exception.